# Markers and infowindows Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to put out markers and info windows from an api with a for loop but only get the last in the list. I have in the for loop because I need to loop through the API and base my information on that. But in my sense I should put out the markers in the loop as well or?

```
    //get all the restaurants which are open
$.getJSON(uri, function(data) {
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var place = data.response.groups[0].items[i].venue.name;
        var placeLat = data.response.groups[0].items[i].venue.location.lat;
        var placeLng = data.response.groups[0].items[i].venue.location.lng;
        var placeAddress = data.response.groups[0].items[i].venue.location.formattedAddress;
        var openPlace = data.response.groups[0].items[i].venue.hours;
        var placeGenre = data.response.groups[0].items[i].venue.categories[0].shortName;
        console.log(place, placeLat, placeLng, placeAddress, openPlace)
        var placePosition = {
            lat: placeLat,
            lng: placeLng
        }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: placePosition,
            map: map
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place + ' | ' + placeGenre + '</strong><br>' + placeAddress + '<br>' + openPlace + '</div>');
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
});
map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } 
    else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }
```

Thanks for the anticipation

Comment: is my answer is helpful or do you have any other problem?

Comment: I've tried this and multiple other solutions nothing works. It sets the one location but for every marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and done the code.

**1st Method:**
Actually the IIFE is useful for this senario.

```
(function(place, placeGenre, placeAddress, openPlace, map, marker){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place + ' | ' + placeGenre + '</strong><br>' + placeAddress + '<br>' + openPlace + '</div>');
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    })
})(place, placeGenre, placeAddress, openPlace, map, marker)
```

**2nd Method:**
Call a function inside your loop and then pass the values.

```
setInfowindow(place, placeGenre, placeAddress, openPlace, map, marker, infowindow);
```

Define setInfowindow function outside:

```
function setInfowindow(place, placeGenre, placeAddress, openPlace, map, marker, infowindow) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place + ' | ' + placeGenre + '</strong><br>' + placeAddress + '<br>' + openPlace + '</div>');
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi the solution to change the for loop didn't work!

Comment: Please provide any plunker url for this.

Comment: It seems that the function google.maps.event.addListener cannot take more than one? If I do:

      console.log(place)

the locations are plotted in the console, but if I do the console within the addListener function it only takes one location.

Comment: Here's a Fiddle of the code! @AnkitPandey

http://jsfiddle.net/1wozLxem/

Comment: @Chilibiff If you are facing any other issue then please infom.

Comment: Awesome, tried the second solutions and that works! @AnkitPandey